# Populating an Array using Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Still trying to learn my firebasics with firebase in Swift right now. I'm having trouble populating an array using firebase. The array will be used to populate a collectionView. My code right now is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView!.register(locationCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "locationCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.collectionView!.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

    myFirebaseFunc()

}

func myFirebaseFunc () {
    let locationRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().queryOrdered(byChild: "Location")
    locationRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            var sorted = ((snapshot.value! as AnyObject).allValues as NSArray).value(forKey: "name") as! NSArray
            sorted = sorted[0] as! NSArray
            for element in sorted {
                let m = MyStruct(name: element as! String)
                self.myArray.append(m)
            }
            print(self.myArray) //array is correctly populated
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
    print(self.myArray) //array is suddenly empty

}
```

JSON Data:

```
{
  "Location" : [ {
    "address" : "602 Pacific Coast Hwy, Huntington Beach, CA 92648",
    "hours" : "Sun 8am-8pm, Mon - Sat 8am-9pm",
    "name" : "Huntington Beach",
    "phoneNumber" : "(714) 536-TACO(8226)"
  }, {
    "address" : "3014 W Balboa Blvd, Newport Beach, CA 92663",
    "hours" : "Sun 8am-8pm, Mon - Sat 8am-9pm",
    "name" : "Newport Beach",
    "phoneNumber" : "(949) 723-TACO(8226)"
  } ]
}
```

After using the debugger, it appears that my main is that the inside of observeSingleEvent is never called, and thusly the array isn't being populated. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: So observeSingleEvent is being called now, and myArray is being filled correctly, but when myArray is called anywhere outside the observeSingleEvent the array says it is empty even though inside observeSingleEvent it is populated correctly.

Comment: A quick first guess is that your code probably doesn't have permission to read the data. Read more here on how to detect that: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24788/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-ios#t=201610211354116706566

Comment: Is printing `snapshot.value` giving some value or it's nil?

Comment: Frank I do have permission to read the data, I just set the firebase rules to always true. @Zaid, printing snaphot.value prints the JSON database, sorted prints just the names, and printing myarray inside  observeSingleEvent prints the correct MyStruct array; however, printing myarray anywhere else results in an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way you are looking for,

`observeSingleEvent` is async method, so you won't get output until it get executed and fetched data from Firebase server.

So the best way to handle this async task are two ways,
**1.)** Either load these data when app start from AppDelegate and use here in your ViewController,
**2.)** or show loading indicator until data is fetched from server, and handle it from inside `observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: Even putting it in AppDelegate, it fails to save the data in the array even thoguh it loads it just fine. A loading indicator is interesting, but I don't think it will help if I cant

Comment: get the data in a list in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelEliot, Yes AppDelegate still need loading so you need to handle using loading indicator.